# Access outside Controller from Directive template

Tags: angularjs, binding, scope

I have the following HTML page (main page, where a `HeaderController` is inside a `PageController`):

```
<div ng-controller="PageController as pageController">
    <page-header ng-cloak></page-header>
</div>
```

This is my `PageController`, with a `PageName` property inside:

```
export class PageController {

    public static ControllerDeclaration = ["$http", "$scope", PageController];

    public PageName: string = "New Page";

    constructor(private $http: angular.IHttpService, private $scope: angular.IScope) {
    }

}
```

For the `pageHeader` directive, I use the following template, which want to access pageController from the outside:

```
        <a class="page-edit">
            <span class="page-name">
                {{pageController.PageName}}
            </span>

            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        </a>
```

However, that binding results in a blank instead of the page name. So I guess it cannot understand `pageController`.

Search through StackOverflow articles, I try using scope by adding the following declaration to the main page HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="PageController as pageController">
    <page-header page-controller="pageController" ng-cloak></page-header>
</div>
```

and to the directive:

```
.directive("pageHeader", Directives.PageHeader)

// This is Directives.PageHeader function:
return {
        templateUrl: "/Scripts/angular-app/templates/page/header.html",
        restrict: "E",
        controller: Controllers.HeaderController.ControllerDeclaration,
        controllerAs: "headerController",
        scope: {
            pageController: "=pageController",
        },
    };
```

However, the binding still fails. Is there a way to debug this process? Could you tell me the best design, in case I am doing wrongly?

Comment: confusing yourself passing in whole controller object. Your directive is using `controllerAs:'headerController'` so you need that object referenced in the view or remove controllerAs

Comment: Yeah, I need to use `headerController` as well, but also `pageController` from the upper (wrapper) div because the `PageName` is in `pageController`. Is it possible to have both (that's what I trying to achieve using scope)?

Comment: You would have 2 different instances of the controller, so that would not work for you. You need to communicate from controller to directive through a service, passing data to directive or through events. I recommend you use a service though. Good luck!

Comment: @Peter_Fretter Thanks, will look into it. I am using Google for it, but do you recommend any design/design pattern/example for my specific purpose?

Comment: @Peter_Fretter Thanks for your reply, sorry for the delay, I have been busy. Could you make it an answer so I can mark it? The `Service` work like a charm for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have 2 different instances of the controller, so that would not work for you. You need to communicate from controller to directive through a service, passing data to directive or through events. I recommend you use a service though. Good luck!